# Can't get asp.net textfield from codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I have a small form in an aspx page. This form is rendered within a jQuery dialog. I put two buttons (jQuery buttons) within this dialog. Due those are not an aspx buttons I had to do the postback manually when a jQuery dialog button is pressed, like this:

The dialog:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var dlg = $('#dialog_renombrar').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 360,
        buttons: {
            "Aceptar": function () {
                __doPostBack('rnmbrFchr', null);
            },
            "Cancelar": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

The form:

```
<div
    align="center"
    id="dialog_renombrar"
    style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:none; 
        overflow:auto">
    <table 
        cellspacing="2" 
        width="100%" 
        align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Documento:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox 
                    ID="nombre_antiguo" 
                    Enabled="false"
                    style="width:100%;"
                    runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Nuevo nombre:
            </td>
            <td>
                <cc1:SWCTextBox 
                    ID="SWCTextBox3"
                    MarcarObligatorio="true"
                    style="width:100%; height:90%" 
                    runat="server"></cc1:SWCTextBox>
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="itemkey" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Then in the codebehind when postback is performed I can't acces a textfield. Can't do:

```
Request.Forms["SWCTextField3"]
```

Neither the value nor the instant object are visible.

I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just do the post via AJAX, if you are already using jQuery anyway. Post the data to a page method.

Comment: @Akram you might want to rephrase your comment, it comes off rather harshly.

Comment: I'd like but I have to do postback.

Comment: @antoni: Would you please try to accept some of the answers on your questions. This way you reward people that make efforts trying to help you.

Comment: At the moment i'm not a registered user, i can't. I'm going to register soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual ID of the textbox by looking at the page source when it's served up. By default ASP.NET will mangle the IDs on the page to ensure they remain unique. If you're using .NET 4 then you can override this behaviour by setting the page directive `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: I think there is a problem submiting data.

Answer (score 0):

If postback is a must, perhaps you could tack-on the textbox contents as a querystring parameter of the URL?

Comment: This is a solution dealing with string. But afterwards I have to do the same but uploading a binary file instead of a string.